# Resize a Google Maps div when the user swipe up or down in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery-mobile

Based upon this jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/kc5xvv3a/) and using jquery mobile, can you tell me how can I have the Google Maps div to be resized When the user scrolls the listview at the bottom, keeping a minimum of 25% of the "main" div for the map but allowing the user to keep scrolling the listview?

I tried to intercept the swipedown and swipeup events

```
$('#mydiv').on('swipedown',function(){alert("swipedown..");} );
$('#mydiv').on('swipeup',function(){alert("swipeup..");} );
```

but I have no idea how to resize the google maps div and be certain that I always keep 25% of the place.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Frédéric

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be a better option to not use swipe, but have a button in which you would enter in the values for the height and width in which then would submit the changes to your CSS div class if you have one.

Comment: I would also recommend looking at https://api.jquery.com/resize/ for help as well. It appears to be pretty easy to follow.

Comment: Thank you for your UX advice... However, I need that the div to be resized when the user swipe the list.

Comment: Ok. I think you might have to do a listener event then and then fire off a function.  I will ask around though to see if I can find out another alternative. I think this link should help:  [LINK TO MY THEORY](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/event_swipe.asp)

Comment: I think you can also put within the function $("#mydiv").height($mydiv.height()); for swipe up and I am not sure if you want to handle side swipe either though?

Comment: One other comment is to see if you can write the function with the proper format instead of having it on one line. The reason is it will make it easier when you have to write longer functions on events or if you don't know how to see if you can write a piece of code to have it call the function within the event.

Comment: Seansanders: The link you provided only works with left and right swipe. I need to react with an up and down swipe.

Comment: The one-line commands are proper format in javascript. You can call a callback function outside of the scope of the main function or embed the code. Anyway, this is really not the point nor the problem. May I suggest you fork my jsfiddle and try your solution? Maybe there is something I didn't understand. Anyway, thank you for your intervention in my problem. It's appreciated...